# Getting big data through SignalR - Blazor

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor

I have a component library that uses JS code to generate an image as a base64 string and the image needs to be transposed to C#. The image size is larger than [MaximumReceiveMessageSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.huboptions.maximumreceivemessagesize?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Can I get the value of the MaximumReceiveMessageSize property in C#? I need a way to correctly split the picture into chunks, or some other way to transfer it.

My component can be used in a Wasm or Server application. I can't change the value of the MaximumReceiveMessageSize property.

Thanks

Comment: Use streaming https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stream-from-javascript-to-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a stream as described in the [Stream from JavaScript to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stream-from-javascript-to-net) solved my problem.

From Microsoft docs:

In JavaScript:

```
function streamToDotNet() {
    return new Uint8Array(10000000);
}
```

In C# code:

```
var dataReference = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSStreamReference>("streamToDotNet");
using var dataReferenceStream = await dataReference.OpenReadStreamAsync(maxAllowedSize: 10_000_000);
var outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "file.txt");
using var outputFileStream = File.OpenWrite(outputPath);
await dataReferenceStream.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
```

In the preceding example: JS is an injected IJSRuntime instance. The dataReferenceStream is written to disk (file.txt) at the current user's temporary folder path (GetTempPath).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).